# Android-studio. Не отображается изображение при вызове в R.drawable

Tags: java, android, android-drawable

Подскажите, сейчас работаю над приложением для занятий спортом, хотела бы сделать перечень упражнений с картинками и описанием. Создала метод Sport с переменной sports, где указала наименование упражнения, его описание и изображение. Добавила необходимое мне изображение в формате PNG в папку drawable, но при его вызове в R.drawable. он у меня не отображается (Наименование PUP). В чем может быть ошибка? размер изображения 8,58 КБ.

```
public class Sport {
private String name;
private String description;
private int imageResourceId;

private Sport(String name, String description, int imageResourceId){
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.imageResourceId = imageResourceId;
}

public static final Sport[] sports = {
        new Sport("Жим гантелей сидя", "1. Удерживайте гантели в каждой руке, сядьте на скамью.", R.drawable.Pup)

};
```

}

Comment: вставьте в вопрос код, где вы отображаете картинку

Comment: Слежу за вашими вопросами, на один даже отвечал. Попробуйте, пожалуйста, не бежать сразу на StackOverflow и задавать вопрос, а хотя бы погуглите ошибку.

Comment: Данный вопрос я задавала 2 месяца назад, вы очень оперативно, спасибо! И на него я самостоятельно дала так же ответ два месяца назад и самостоятельно с этим разобралась, вдруг у кого то будет такая же проблема, тогда будет на что ориентироваться.
Не переживайте, у меня вместо стартовой страницы не StackOverflow стоит и если я задаю вопрос, значит нуждаюсь в совете опытных специалистов. А если я успеваю разобраться раньше чем мне ответят тут, то отвечаю сама на свой же вопрос, вдруг в будущем кто то так же столкнется с такой проблемой. Каждый с чего то начинает, так что не нужно осуждать.

Answer (score 3):

Разобралась, android-studio не разбирает названия изображений в которых присутствуют буквы в верхнем регистре